# how to make spring roo menu tree folding like JQuery menu

Tags: spring, menu, spring-roo, jspx

Question is self explanatory. I need Tree style menu, which menu category can be folded ...

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to search different css styles for your need. There is nothing to do with Spring ROO specifically.

I think you should explore the Bootstrap CSS provided by twitter. It is a very good and standard CSS library. Check out this [link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Its available to download on github.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.